# Scatter matrices for class separability

Tags: matrix, machine-learning, computer-vision, cluster-analysis

I found that scatter matrices are useful to calculate within and between class separability. [This](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/feature_selection/node2.html) link gives more information about them. My question is as follows:

Suppose there are 4-classes, I should get 4 within-class scatter matrices and `4C2 = 6` between-class scatter matrices. Whereas, we get only single within and between class matrices. Any explanation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in the link you've provided (which is kind of brief) you can see the per-class scatter matrices S_i. But "between-class" doesn't mean "between all pairs of classes", it means something closer to "among all classes" -- so there's a single "between-class" matrix.

Comment: so fir per-class scatter matrices, if I don't sum everything up into a single matrix, then I should get separate per-class matrices, right?

Comment: Yes, S_i individually are per-class. \Sum P_i S_i is S_W.